# unable to load an specific url without authentication

Tags: authentication

I want to show this following url but when I try to show it, it goes to authentication page while if you copy and paste this url in your browser it will show the requested page without authentication.
I am using phpdesigner and easyphp in which I confront this problem. I try using file_get_content, curl_init, ... but still can't show the following url.
Thanks in advance.

http://sepehrreservation.iranhrc.ir/Systems/FA/Reservation/Flight_NewReservation_Search.aspx?itinerary=THR|MHD|2017-02-28|

Comment: I can click on it and it doesn't need any authentication... maybe clear your browser cache or try an incognito browser

Comment: this url will be change every time in program but I can't get the result like it is shown in browser when I want to get its content like $url = 'http://sepehrreservation.iranhrc.ir/Systems/FA/Reservation/Flight_NewReservation_Search.aspx?itinerary=THR|MHD|2017-02-24|';
$homepage = file_get_contents($url);  it will show an authentication page